# The internal workings of .htaccess and .htpasswd

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, apache2

I know if I block a drectory with .htaccess and .htpasswd a popup appears asking for username and password. Now my question is , so far I know, only javascript can make popup boxes. So, the server must have sent me some javascript code that pops the box How do I see that code? I am using mozilla in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

No server doesn't send any JS code to browser.

Read more about [**`Basic_access_authentication`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

> When the server wants the user agent to authenticate itself towards
>   the server, it can send a request for authentication.
>
> This request should be sent using the `HTTP 401 Not Authorized response
>   code containing a WWW-Authenticate HTTP header.`
>
> The `WWW-Authenticate header` for basic authentication (used most often)
>   is constructed as following:
>
> ```
> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Auth Required"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is not Javascript that makes the pop up appear. It is the browser that gets an error response when it makes an HTTP requests. So browser asks the user for an username and password.